# Searching for elements within Python list using conditional statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
main_col = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']
main_row = [['Peter', 18, 'M'], ['Sam', 20, 'M'], ['Carol', 19, 'F'], ['Malcom', 21, 'M'], ['Oliver', 25, 'M'], ['Mellisa', 21, 'F'], ['Minreva', 18, 'F'], ['Bruce', 23, 'M'], ['Clarke', 24, 'M'], ['Zuck', 22, 'M'], ['Slade', 23, 'M'], ['Wade', 21, 'M'], ['Felicity', 22, 'F'], ['Selena', 23, 'F'], ['Ra\'s Al Gul',700, 'M']]
```

I am trying to make a program where `main_col` are column names and `main_row` have row information for each column (in a 2d list).

How can I write a piece of code for a search query which can search row where:

1. Name = 'Carol' and Age = 19.
2. Name = 'Carol' and Gender = 'F'
3. Age= 22 or Gender = 'M'

The following code is giving result for the 3rd part:-

```
search = {'Age' : 22, 'Gender' : 'M'}

for i in search:
    idx = main_col.index(i)
    for j in main_row:
        if(j[idx] == search[i]):
            print(j)
```

Comment: well my code is actually giving output for only 3rd part, can't find a way to code for 1st and 2nd part

Comment: *What* code? And those things all seem very similar; how have you tried parts 1 and 2, and what specifically is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to stick with your pattern, this is an option:**

```
search = {'Age' : 21, 'Gender' : 'M'}

idxs = [ (main_col.index(key), val) for key, val in search.items()]
tmp = [ set(tuple(person) for person in main_row if person[i] == v) for  i, v in idxs ]
res = set.intersection(*tmp)
#=> {('Wade', 21, 'M'), ('Malcom', 21, 'M')}
```

**NOTE:** I used `intersection` to return `AND`, but you can customise to any of the operation available on `set` (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set): `union`, `intersection`, `difference`, ...

---

You can convert to a handy method:

```
def lookup(search, main_row, main_col):
  idxs = [ (main_col.index(key), val) for key, val in search.items()]
  tmp = [ set(tuple(person) for person in main_row if person[i] == v) for  i, v in idxs ]
  return set.intersection(*tmp)

lookup({'Age' : 21}, main_row, main_col)
#=> {('Wade', 21, 'M'), ('Mellisa', 21, 'F'), ('Malcom', 21, 'M')}
lookup({'Age' : 21, 'Gender' : 'M'}, main_row, main_col)
#=> {('Malcom', 21, 'M'), ('Wade', 21, 'M')}
lookup({'Age' : 21, 'Gender' : 'M', 'Name': 'Malcom'}, main_row, main_col)
#=> {('Malcom', 21, 'M')}
```

---

**Anyway, I'd suggest to use a dict from main_row:**

```
main_row = [['Peter', 18, 'M'], ['Sam', 20, 'M'], ['Carol', 19, 'F'], ['Malcom', 21, 'M'], ['Oliver', 25, 'M'], ['Mellisa', 21, 'F'], ['Minreva', 18, 'F'], ['Bruce', 23, 'M'], ['Clarke', 24, 'M'], ['Zuck', 22, 'M'], ['Slade', 23, 'M'], ['Wade', 21, 'M'], ['Felicity', 22, 'F'], ['Selena', 23, 'F'], ['Ra\'s Al Gul',700, 'M'], ['Oliver', 31, 'M']]
```

This builds the dictionary `people`, leaving apart the first list of headers:

```
people = [ {'name':name, 'age':age, 'gender':gender} for name, age, gender in main_row]
#=> [{'name': 'Peter', 'age': 18, 'gender': 'M'}, {'name': 'Sam', 'age': 20, 'gender': 'M'}, ....
```

Then you can query for example in this way:

```
next(person for person in people if person['name'] == "Oliver" and person['age'] == 31 )
#=> {'name': 'Oliver', 'age': 31, 'gender': 'M'}


the_21_years_old = [ person for person in people if  person['age'] == 21 ]
#=> [{'name': 'Malcom', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'M'}, {'name': 'Mellisa', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'F'}, {'name': 'Wade', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'M'}]
```

You can the do whatever you need with the returned "records":

```
for person in the_21_years_old:
  print(person['name'], person['age'])

# Malcom 21
# Mellisa 21
# Wade 21
```

Answer (score 3):

You could give this a try, its somewhat complicated but should get the job done:

```
AND = 'and'
OR = 'or'

# Check if the array is a match
def is_found(value, aggregator, search_terms):
  if aggregator == AND:
    is_found = True
    for col, val in search_terms.items():
      if value[val['idx']] != val['val']:
        is_found = False
        break
  else:
    is_found = False
    for col, val in search_terms.items():
      if value[val['idx']] == val['val']:
        is_found = True
        break
  return is_found

# Perform the search
def search(columns, values, aggregator, search_filters):
  # Format the search values into something we can use
  # {
  #    'col': { 'idx': <column index>, 'val': <search value> }
  # } 
  search_terms = { 
    col: { 'idx': columns.index(col), 'val': val } 
    for col, val in search_filters.items()
  }

  return [
    val
    for val in values
    if is_found(val, aggregator, search_terms)
  ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main_col = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']
  main_row = [['Peter', 18, 'M'], ['Sam', 20, 'M'], ['Carol', 19, 'F'], ['Malcom', 21, 'M'], ['Oliver', 25, 'M'], ['Mellisa', 21, 'F'], ['Minreva', 18, 'F'], ['Bruce', 23, 'M'], ['Clarke', 24, 'M'], ['Zuck', 22, 'M'], ['Slade', 23, 'M'], ['Wade', 21, 'M'], ['Felicity', 22, 'F'], ['Selena', 23, 'F'], ['Ra\'s Al Gul',700, 'M']]

  search_filter = {
    'Age': 22, 'Gender': 'M'
  }
  print(search(main_col, main_row, OR ,search_filter))

  search_filter = {
    'Name': 'Carol', 'Age': 19
  }
  print(search(main_col, main_row, AND ,search_filter))
```

Comment: hey can you explain why haven't you initialized is_found = True in both cases, why one is initialized True and other False

Comment: its because of how it handles **and** and **or**. For the **and**, we only need it to be true when all the search terms match, if it something doesn’t match we flag it as false then break out of the loop. While we do the opposite for **or**, we initially need to set it to false and then flag it as true for any matches.